# ML for numerical transformations

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a small dataset of size 200. The dataset is very simple: each row consists of a real-valued number in the range [0, 1] that maps to a single label. There are 24 labels in total, and the essence of my task would be to train a classifier to basically find a range that maps to a label.

There are 2 approaches I can think of. The first one would be SVCs because of their ability to separate the input plane into 24 regions, which is what I need. However, when I tried coding it, I ended up with some terrible results: the classifier did not learn anything, and would spit out the same label regardless of the input value.

The second approach I am considering is a neural network, but given the lack of features and training data, I highly doubt the feasibility of this approach.

If requested, I can share my SVC code that I developed with scikit-learn.

Here's a look at my data that I've dumped onto the terminal:

```
Label: Min, Mean, Max
{0: [0.96, 0.98, 1.0],
 1: [0.15, 0.36, 0.92],
 2: [0.14, 0.56, 0.98],
 3: [0.37, 0.7, 1.0],
 4: [0.23, 0.23, 0.23],
 6: [0.41, 0.63, 0.97],
 7: [0.13, 0.38, 0.61],
 8: [0.11, 0.68, 1.0],
 9: [0.09, 0.51, 1.0],
 10: [0.19, 0.61, 0.97],
 11: [0.26, 0.41, 0.57],
 12: [0.29, 0.72, 0.95],
 13: [0.63, 0.9, 0.99],
 14: [0.06, 0.55, 1.0],
 15: [0.1, 0.64, 1.0],
 16: [0.26, 0.58, 0.95],
 17: [0.29, 0.88, 1.0],
 21: [0.58, 0.79, 1.0],
 22: [0.24, 0.59, 0.94],
 23: [0.12, 0.62, 0.95]}
```

As you can see, the data is all over the place, but I want to find out whether it is possible to find a range that each label best represents.

I'd appreciate if someone could tell me if I'm on the right track or not. Thanks!

Comment: Well... what are your assumptions about that data? Some model-ideas?

Comment: Well, the biggest assumption I'm making is that the ranges that the labels represent do not overlap with each other. So, effectively, my labels will partition [0, 1] into 24 unique, distinct spaces.

As for model ideas, I've listed 2 out of which I've tried one that doesn't seem to work. :]

Comment: Why not show your data?

Comment: Have edited with some data. Hope that helps!

Comment: This data is kind of untrainable. At least the assumption about 24 unique distinct spaces for 24 classes is wrong or heavily punished by the variance. There is not much you can do with this data. Either there is a better assumption/model or GaussianNB is in fact very near the optimum.

Comment: Have edited my code with the min, mean, and max for each label. Do you still feel that there is nothing to salvage from this data?

Comment: Yes, according to the assumption (which i formalized) it's (nearly) like random data (which can't be predicted; although min/max is not a good estimator here; but it indicates this). So you need some new assumption. (Both current answers are useless with this data)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the insight! What would you recommend?

Comment: To read some ML-tutorial about the theoretical basics. There is not much help here as we don't have your data or know the environment. Again: min/mean/max is not a good estimator here to show data-statistics. Many kinds of different distributions per class samples are possible which are not much seen by those values.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Here's my data: http://pastebin.com/raw/idVXjwgZ

As for the environment, I've basically developed a classifier that automatically assigns probability values to a given document (I cannot mention what the value represents). The label is a score based on a certain metric (the same metric that the classifier is working with) that an unbiased expert has given the very same document. I want to see if there is any correlation between my classifier's output and the expert's label.

In essence, I want to learn a numerical transformation formula for this data, if it exists.

Comment: Look at the plot within my updated answer and judge yourself.

Comment: Just wondering... why did you plot the labels on the horizontal axis and not vice versa? Intuitively, it's supposed to be the other way...

Comment: I like this representation more. But feel free to do a scatter-plot with class-colors (maybe not nice in 1d-space).

Comment: But yeah, I've got your point. There's something fundamentally wrong with the data. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume, that your samples per class are somewhat centered (but still noisy; there can be overlappings), probably the most natural classifier available within sklearn is [Gaussian Naive Bayes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#gaussian-naive-bayes) where we assume those points per class are following the normal-distribution.

Here is some code, which builds some fake data, classifies it and evaluate:

```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
np.random.seed(1)


""" Data-params + Data-generation """
N_CLASSES = 24
N_SAMPLES_PER_CLASS = 10
SIGMA = 0.01

class_centers = np.random.random(size=N_CLASSES)
# ugly code with bad numpy-style
X = []
for class_center in class_centers:
    samples = np.random.normal(size=N_SAMPLES_PER_CLASS)*SIGMA
    for sample in samples + class_center:
        X.append(sample)
Y = []
for ind, c in enumerate(class_centers):
    for s in range(N_SAMPLES_PER_CLASS):
        Y.append(ind)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1)
Y = np.array(Y)

""" Split & Fit & Eval """
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

et = GaussianNB()
et.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Prediction on test')
preds = et.predict(X_test)
print(preds)

print('Original samples')
print(y_test)

print('Accuracy-score')
print(accuracy_score(y_test, preds))
```

Output

```
Prediction on test
[10  7  3  7  8  3 23  3 11 19  7 20  8 15 11 13 18 11  3 16  8  9  8 12]
Original samples
[10  7  3  7 10 22 15 22 15 19  7 20  8 15 23 13 18 11 22  0 10 17  8 12]
Accuracy-score
0.583333333333
```

Of course the result is highly dependent on `N_SAMPLES_PER_CLASS` and `SIGMA`.

**EDIT:**

As you now presented your data, it's obvious that my assumption does not hold.
See the following plot done by this code (file was stripped from `[]()`; people should really post csv-compatible data!):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv('idVXjwgZ.txt', usecols=[0,1], names=['x', 'y'])
sns.swarmplot(data=data, x='y', y='x')
plt.show()
```

Plot:

[image]

Now just think about observing some `x` and you need to decide on `y`. Pretty hard for most *x-ranges*.

There is obviously also the class-balance problem which explains the output of class 14 for most predictions.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Yes, you've assumed correctly that there are overlaps. I've edited my post to show the data.

I've also tried out your method, and this is what I'm getting as the output:
`[14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14]`
This is similar to what the LinearSVC was giving me.

Answer (score 1):

If the label ranges don't overlap, then this is not an ML problem; it's a simple list-sorting task.  Sort the data on the real number; group by label.  Within each label, take the min and max values; that's your range.

If you need partitions instead, then sort the ranges in order of their real values.  For each pair of adjacent classes, take the median of the boundary values and make that the partition between the classes.

For instance, given the list of 12 values in 3 classes

```
(0.10, 3), (0.40, 2), (0.11, 3), (0.24, 1),
(0.20, 1), (0.21, 1), (0.12, 3), (0.41, 2),
(0.18, 3), (0.42, 2), (0.46, 2), (0.22, 1)
```

Sort the list by the first value in each pair:

```
(0.10, 3), (0.11, 3), (0.12, 3), (0.18, 3),
(0.20, 1), (0.21, 1), (0.22, 1), (0.24, 1),
(0.40, 2), (0.41, 2), (0.42, 2), (0.46, 2),
```

You now have a range for each label:

```
3 [0.10 - 0.18]
1 [0.20 - 0.24]
2 [0.40 - 0.46]
```

If you want partition values, just take the boundary averages, and you have the values 0.19 and 0.32 to separate your classes.

Comment: I apologise. I never meant to say they do not overlap. They in fact do. I however, wanted to find the best exclusive range that a label represents... Hope that clarifies things!